# Excel - Copy adjacent data value to another sheet based on certain text, till end of sheet

Tags: excel, vba, copy

So I have two excel documents.

One to take data from (RESULT.xlsm).

Another to insert data into (Summary.xls).

What I want is the adjacent cell values next to the hightlighted names to get inserted into Summary.xls under the respective columns. So I tried recording a macro but what happens is only the first record gets inserted.

Since only two links are allowed for me, i put it all in one picture: 
http://i50.tinypic.com/9veihl.png

Note: There are multiple records in RESULT.xlsm and the screenshot shows just one.

I would like help on how I can extract data from all the set of records and insert in Summary.xlsx

Here's the recorded macro code:

```
Sub Summ()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="Summary.xlsx"
Windows.Arrange ArrangeStyle:=xlVertical
Windows("RESULT.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Air System Name", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B10").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Summary.xlsx").Activate
Range("A5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RESULT.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Floor Area", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Summary.xlsx").Activate
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RESULT.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Total coil load", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B27").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Summary.xlsx").Activate
Range("C5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RESULT.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Sensible coil load", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B28").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Summary.xlsx").Activate
Range("D5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Windows("RESULT.xlsm").Activate
Cells.Find(What:="Max block L/s", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("B30").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("Summary.xlsx").Activate
Range("E5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A6").Select

End Sub
```

I've also attached the excel files at mediafire:

[Excel files](http://www.mediafire.com/?emxkkg6910588su)

Please do help.

Thanks alot:)

Comment: If there are multiple records in the source file then a better approach would be to loop through ColumnA in RESULT.xlsm and look for your search text.  When you hit a new record (eg. each time "Air System Name" shows up) then start a new line in the summary table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked up at alot of resources and tried to follow what @Tim Williams told me to and stumbled across this page (the last part): https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/text-functions/column-sets-to-rows

They had a solution almost close to my problem, so I made a few modifications and I'm done:D

Note: This is within the same document, different sheets.

The code of it:

```
Dim LR As Long, NR As Long, Rw As Long
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsOUT As Worksheet
Dim HdrCol As Range, Hdr As String, strRESET As String

Set wsData = Sheets("Sheet1")   'source data
Set wsOUT = Sheets("Sheet2")    'output sheet
strRESET = "    Air System Name "    'this value will cause the record row to increment

LR = wsData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'end of incoming data
Set HdrCol = wsOUT.Range("1:1").Find(strRESET, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)      'find the reset category column
If HdrCol Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The key string '" & strRESET & _
    "' could not be found on the output sheet."
Exit Sub
End If

NR = wsOUT.Cells(Rows.Count, HdrCol.Column) _
        .End(xlUp).Row      'current output end of data

Set HdrCol = Nothing

On Error Resume Next
For Rw = 1 To LR
Hdr = wsData.Range("A" & Rw).Value



If (Hdr = "    Air System Name ") Then
NR = NR + 1
End If

If Hdr <> "" Then

    Set HdrCol = wsOUT.Range("1:1").Find(Hdr, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not HdrCol Is Nothing Then
        wsOUT.Cells(NR, HdrCol.Column).Value _
                = wsData.Range("B" & Rw).Value

        Set HdrCol = Nothing
    End If
End If
Next Rw
```

The only little problem is the space. In my excel document, my report has trailing and leading spaces, and this doesn't match with my sheet2 columns headers, I kind of temporarily fixed it, since I looked around and couldn't find a way to automatically trim all the space from the whole column.

So that's it:)